# Passing arguments from one asp.net page to another using jQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I need to pass 4 arguments (3 strings and one comma separated list) from an ASP.NET page to another ASP.NET page using jQuery. The destination page ought to be launched as a separate window, which works fine with the following jQuery snippet:

```
$('#sourcePageBtn').click(function(){
   window.open("destinationPage.aspx");
   return false;
});
```

How can I pass the arguments to the destination page? I am trying to avoid the query string to pass the arguments because:

1. I don't want to show the url arguments (which can also be very long) in the destination window.
2. There are some special characters like ',/,\, & etc. in the string arguments.

Please suggest.

**Edit:**
I'm trying to access the arguments in the script section of the aspx file i.e.

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load ( object src, EventArgs e) 
    {
     //Creating dynamic asp controls here
    }
</script>
```

My specific need for the arguments in the Page_Load of the script section stems from the fact that I am creating a few dynamic Chart controls in the Page_Load which depend on these arguments.

cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Initial Thoughts (before solution created)

1. Use [POST](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/#postmethod) for large data instead of GET. With POST no querystring will be used for data and therefore URL length restriction isn't a concern. (The max URL length differs between browsers so you're right to stay away from it when large data is moving).
2. Special URL characters can be [encoded](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/http_footnotes.html#urlencoding) to be passed in the query string so that shouldn't be an issue.

Alternatively you might store the data on the server side from the first page, and have the second page pick it up from the server side. But this is overkill. And it makes you do unneeded server programming.

Passing state via HTTP calls is standard practice. You shouldn't try to circumvent it. Work with it. All the facilities are built in for you. Now it's just up to jQuery to provide us some help...

**Note:** *Be careful* using jQuery for main app features in case JavaScript is disabled in the browser. In most cases your web application should be usable at a basic level even when JavaScript is disabled. After that's working, layer on JavaScript/jQuery to make the experience even better, even awesome.

## Edit: Solution (with ASP.NET processing)

Key resources for solution implementation are:

- [How use **POST from jQuery**](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.post) - initiates the request, passes arguments, gets response
- [jQuery **context argument**](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery) - this is how the popup window DOM is accessed/affected from the main window

**How it works**: From a main page, a POST occurs and results are displayed in a popup window. It happens in this order:

- The main script opens a popup window (if it doesn't already exist)
- main script waits for popup window to fully initialize
- main script POSTs (using AJAX) arguments to another page  (sends a request)
- main script receives response and displays it in the popup window.

Effectively we have posted data to a popup window and passed arguments to the processing.

***Three pages follow and they constitute the complete solution. I had all 3 sitting on my desktop and it works in Google Chrome stable version 3.0.195.38. Other browsers untested. You'll also need [jquery-1.3.2.js](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery) sitting in the same folder.***

**main_page.html**

This is the expansion of the logic you provided. Sample uses a link instead of a form button, but it has the same `id=sourcePageBtn`.

This sample passes two key/value pairs when the POST occurs (just for example). You will pass key/value pairs of your choice in this place.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<a id="sourcePageBtn" href="javascript:void(0);">click to launch popup window</a>

<script>

$(function() {
 $('#sourcePageBtn').click( function() {

  // Open popup window if not already open, and store its handle into jQuery data.
  ($(window).data('popup') && !$(window).data('popup').closed) 
   || $(window).data('popup', window.open('popup.html','MyPopupWin'));

  // Reference the popup window handle.
  var wndPop = $(window).data('popup');

  // Waits until popup is loaded and ready, then starts using it
  (waitAndPost = function() {
   // If popup not loaded, Wait for 200 more milliseconds before retrying
   if (!wndPop || !wndPop['ready']) 
    setTimeout(waitAndPost, 200);

   else  { 
       // Logic to post (pass args) and display result in popup window...
    // POST args name=John, time=2pm to the process.aspx page...
    $.post('process.aspx', { name: "John", time: "2pm" }, function(data) {
     // and display the response in the popup window <P> element.
     $('p',wndPop.document).html(data);
    });
   }
  })(); //First call to the waitAndPost() function.


 });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**popup.html**

This is the popup window that is targeted from the main page. You'll see a reference to popup.html in the jQuery script back in the main page.

There's a "trick" here to set `window['ready'] = true` when the popup window DOM is finally loaded. The main script keeps checking and  waiting until this popup is ready.

```
<html>

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
 <!--  The example P element to display HTTP response inside -->
 <p>page is loaded</p>
</body>

<script>
    $(function() {
     window['ready'] = true;
    });
</script>

</html>
```

**process.aspx.cs (C# - ASP.NET process.aspx page)**

The dynamic server page the arguments are POSTed to by the main page script. 
The AJAX arguments arrive in the [Page.Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.request.aspx) collection.
The output is delivered back as plain text for this example, but you can customize the response for your apps requirements.

```
public partial class process : System.Web.UI.Page {

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        // Access "name" argument.
        string strName = Request["name"] ?? "(no name)";
        // Access "time" argument. 
        string strTime = Request["time"] ?? "(no time)";

        Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        Response.Write(string.Format("{0} arrives at {1}", strName, strTime));
    }

    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        // Just to suppress Page from outputting extraneous HTML tags.
        //base.Render(writer); //don't run.
    }

}
```

Results of this are displayed into the popup window by the original/main page. 
So the contents of the popup window are overwritten with `"[name] arrives at [time]"`

---

Main References: [HTTP Made Really Easy](http://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/), [jQuery Ajax members and examples.](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax)

Comment: Thanks. I need to launch the destination page from jQuery button click handler as I'm collecting the ids and text values of few HTML elements in the jQuery button click. Secondly, I need to launch a new page, instead of a redirect. window.open() does that for me but I don't think it supports a POST like behavior.

Comment: I edited to include a link to jQuery POST examples. Am I heading in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks again. Much of your reply makes sense to me. And $.POST() does take the control to the destination page. But the control comes back to the source page. Also, the destination page doesn't get launched as a separate page.

Comment: I'm still hacking at it. Code sample is in progress..., however what's interesting right now is by using the jQuery syntax `$(element, context)` in the MAIN window and by providing the popup's window handle as the context jQuery is accessing the DOM of the popup window and displaying stuff only seen in the popup.  Hopefully .get and .post can be used to affect the popup too... time will tell.

Comment: Solution completed. It opens a poupup window and posts data from your main page to it - the solution uses jQuery/AJAX as you requested. If you just copy and paste the source code into three files, you can run it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your patience and efforts. Almost everything works great. Just that I'm unable to access the arguments in the page load of my ASP.NET destination page. How do I do that? Do I need to modify the page load argument list to receive these arguments?

Comment: I replaced data.html with an ASP.NET dynamic page named `process.aspx` containing server processing of the passed data. Throw all this into an ASP.NET web application to run it.

Comment: Thanks again. I tried accessing the argument using Request["name"], but it always gives me (no name). One thing which I forgot to mention is added as an Edit in the question, i.e. I need to access the arguments in the C# script section of the aspx file.

Comment: @Andriyev: That's odd app behaviour. What you might do is boil it down to a simple scenario around the new problem (of ajax arguments not being seen by ASP.NET), then post a separate question to SO (put in details of browser, version, etc.) You will get more specific answers this way and likely solve it sooner.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a reference to the new window when you open it, ie `var destWin = window.open(...)` then you can access the variables and methods on the destWin window object.  Alternatively you can "reach back" from the destination window with `window.opener`.